# Does the regression line have equicontinuity?

Tags: regression

I was reading [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equicontinuity) wikipedia article.  The article is about equicontinuity.  And my first thought was the regression line. THis question is to more help me understand and to check my understanding.  Please note, I am not very knowledgeable; however, I want to be.

So is the question in the title correct? If not, please explain why.

Comment: Equicontinuity is only interesting for a family of functions. If you're only looking at one function, then it's just plain old continuity.

Are you asking if a line is continuous? Yes, it is.

Comment: Unless closing questions is good, it might not add a lot of value...but whatever...free points :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Equicontinuity is only interesting for a family of functions. If you're only looking at one function, then it's just plain old continuity. Are you asking if a line is continuous? Yes, it is. – Taylor Jan 16 at 3:42